# How to block a set of related email addresses in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, google-contacts

I created a filter so that every email from specific email addresses get deleted. However, it doesn't work at all and all of these emails shown in my Inbox.

This is how I configured the filter.

Gmail -> Setting -> Filters ->

```
Matches: from:(s******9@icloud.com , s*******9@gmail.com , s*******m@yahoo.com)
Do this: Delete it
```

[image]

What should do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of separating multiple email addresses with a comma, you should separate them with `OR`, as per [this Gmail help document](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8870).

```
Matches: from:(s******9@icloud.com OR s*******9@gmail.com OR s*******m@yahoo.com)
Do this: Delete it
```